# Lost All Bookmarks and my google account bookmarks restored to 1.5 Years back

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I am currently using google chrome version: `Version 33.0.1750.117 m`. I daily sign in to my google chrome to my email account in office and delete when I left the office. I do same process since more than 2 years. Today I suddenly found that my all bookmarks are gone and it is showing me almost 1.5 years back bookmarks. I went to "`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\`" and I found yesterday's profile bookmark as file extension and when I opended it, It is in JSON format. I want to restore my all bookmarks. Please help. It is urgent.

Comment: Do you see bookmarks or bookmarks.bak under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` or whichever profile you were using. What does the timestamp say?

Comment: It is showing 19-12-2013

Comment: @buffer and the when I open that file in notepad it is showing different bookmark than it is displaying in google chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome does a bad job on being able to restore bookmarks. If any of the files `Bookmarks` or `Bookmarks.bak` are recent (last good known configuration date) on any of the PC where you used Chrome, you can salvage the bookmarks, else you are out of luck.